# Lower case title with tikzposter package

Tags: tikzposter

I'm new at using tikzposter and would like my poster title to be all lower case except for the first letter of the first word. Something like this:

"Work-in-progress poster title" instead of "WORK-IN-PROGRESS POSTER TITLE"

I have tried using these commands without success:

```
 \MakeLowercase{} 
 \lowercase{}
 \MakeTextLowercase{} (with the textcase package)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tikzposter` class does

```
\gdef\TP@maketitle{
    \centering
    \vbox{
    \@titlegraphic
        \\[\TP@titlegraphictotitledistance]
        \centering
        \color{titlefgcolor}
        {\bfseries \Huge \sc \@title \par}
        \vspace*{1em}
        {\huge \@author \par}
        \vspace*{1em}
        {\LARGE \@institute}
    }
}
```

By the way, the class does `\usepackage{ae}`, which is very silly. Using `\sc` is sillier.

Anyway, taking the example file as a template,

```
\documentclass[
  25pt,
  a0paper,
  portrait,
  margin=0mm,
  innermargin=15mm,
  blockverticalspace=15mm,
  colspace=15mm,
  subcolspace=8mm
]{tikzposter} %Default values for poster format options.

 \tikzposterlatexaffectionproofon %shows small comment on how the poster was made at bottom of poster

%%% Added for avoding small caps in the title
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\TP@maketitle}
  {\bfseries \Huge \sc}
  {\bfseries\Huge}
  {}{}
\makeatother

%%% added for using a good font
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
\substitutefont{OMX}{lmex}{cmex}

% Commands
\newcommand{\bs}{\textbackslash}   % backslash
\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{{\bfseries\color{red}#1}}   % highlights command

% Title, Author, Institute
\title{Using tikzposter}
\author{Pascal Richter, Elena Botoeva, Richard Barnard, \& Dirk Surmann}
\institute{}

% -- PREDEFINED THEMES ---------------------- %
% Choose LAYOUT:  Default, Basic, Rays, Simple, Envelope, Wave, Board, Autumn, Desert,
\usetheme{Autumn}
\usecolorstyle[colorPalette=BrownBlueOrange]{Germany}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

% omitted the rest

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Works regardless of initial case

EDITED for `tikzposter`.  The addition of `\upshape` was required to nullify the small caps:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\newcommand\capone[1]{\caponehelp#1\relax}
\def\caponehelp#1#2\relax{\upshape\uppercase{#1}\lowercase{#2}}
\title{
\capone{work-in-progress}
vs.
\capone{WORK-IN-PROGRESS}
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here with `article`

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\capone[1]{\caponehelp#1\relax}
\def\caponehelp#1#2\relax{\uppercase{#1}\lowercase{#2}}

\begin{document}
\capone{work-in-progress poster title}

\capone{WORK-IN-PROGRESS POSTER TITLE}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this work with `\documentclass{tikzposter}`?

Comment: @samcarter EDITED to make it so.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\makeatletter
\gdef\TP@maketitle{
    \centering
    \vbox{
    \@titlegraphic
        \\[\TP@titlegraphictotitledistance]
        \centering
        \color{titlefgcolor}
        {\bfseries \Huge \@title \par} % <-- removed \sc
        \vspace*{1em}
        {\huge \@author \par}
        \vspace*{1em}
        {\LARGE \@institute}
    }
}
\makeatother


\title{Work in progress}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\end{document}
```

[image]